# SelectedIndexChanged doesn't fire on using DropDownList inside GridView using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I am using DropDownList control inside a GridView I am filling this list from database in the RowBound event. I set the AutoPostBack property to true but the SelectedIndexChached event doesn't fire and when I change selected index nothing happens can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please post your code what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Attach to the RowCommand event of the GridView.  See if this event fires when the postback from the dropdownlist happens.  If so, you can handle it from here.  The reason you might not be getting the notification is because the event bubbles up instead of raises directly, if all this works as mentioned here.

HTH.